# TFS 2010 Error when trying to open Team Projects "TF31001: Cannot connect to Team Foundation Server at..."

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

My instance of TFS 2010 has developed this problem.

When I try and connect to a Team Project in VS 2010 I get this error:

> TF31001: Cannot connect to Team Foundation Server at 'PROJECT COLLECTION'. The server returned the following error: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: serviceDefinition

I have ran the Team Foundation Server 2010 Best Practices Analyzer and it found no problems. I can load the Admin Console fine, everything seems to be in working order, there are no other errors that I have seen and there is nothing in the Event Log that would suggest there has been an issue and there have been no drastic changes to service accounts or SQL Server.

Has anyone seen this error before? If so what did you do to fix it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Delete the cache from below location, then try to connect again.

c:\users\[username]\Appdata\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\3.0\Cache

Comment: Thanks. Worked perfectly.